# ¿Cómo obtengo las filas de un CSV en el que una columna tiene un valor superior a X?

Tags: bash, csv

Me gustaría, a partir de un **fichero** csv (o formatos similares), poder elegir la información de una fila que cumpla con X condición.

Ejemplo:
*Si tengo una en la 2 Columnas y 4 Filas, donde la primera es el nombre y la segunda la nota media, me gustaría hacer un filtro para mostrar solamente los nombres con una nota superior a X.*

Mi duda sobretodo reside en cómo tratar la información de un fichero; programo en C, Java y PY y veo que la metodología es distinta (no hace falta abrir el archivo y tenerlo en bucle de r/w etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongamos que tienes el fichero así:

```
juan,2
pedro,14
julia,7
maría,5
```

Y quieres mostrar las filas en las que la 2.ª columna es mayor que X. Entonces se trata de decir:

```
awk -F, -v X=5 '$2>X' fichero
```

O directamente pasarle el valor a Awk:

```
awk -F, '$2>5' fichero
```

Para el ejemplo que di, el resultado sería:

```
$ awk -F, '$2>5' fichero
pedro,14
julia,7
```

Comment: Vale, probaré a implementarlo pero esto me ha aclarado como "manipular" el fichero.
¡Muchas gracias!